# Plotting empty data in a plotly graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plotly

I have a situation where I have a series of data, with some values missing in the middle. Like below:

[image: X,Y 1,10 1,11 1,9 1,5 1,14 1,10 1,12 1,13 3,5 3,10 3,7 3,1 3,3 3,4 3,8 3,-2]

If you see the data, 2 is missing in the series.

I wish to plot a box plot or a violin plot where, I can have a placeholder for the 2 series, which would mean no data is present for it.

Right now I can plot by inserting 2 and substituting NaNs and it gives a plot like below:

[image]

Is there a better way to plot without manipulating the data, either by use of texts on X Axis or by just having a placeholder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine a [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) and [`seaborn.boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3],
                   'Y': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
                  })
df['X'] = pd.Categorical(df['X'], categories=[1, 2, 3])

sns.boxplot(data=df, x='X', y='Y')
```

Output:

[image]

##### annotating the missing categories:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(data=df, x='X', y='Y')

# positions of the categories in the X-axis
cats = {c: i for i,c in enumerate(df['X'].cat.categories)}
missing = set(df['X'].cat.categories)-set(df['X'])
# {2}

# mid-point of the Y-axis
y_pos = np.mean(ax.get_ylim())

for x in missing:
    ax.annotate('N/A', (cats[x], y_pos), ha='center')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @mozway. This is helpful. Is there anyway to mark the 2, like no data is available, like a text or label there?

Comment: Not automatically, but you can manually use `annotate`